# Chance to crash?

Tags: math

I looked at the game superloop.
You are a character which is either red, green, blue, or yellow. You get a shape assigned: either triangle, quad, pentagon, or circle.
You are traversing on one of three lanes on which are obstacles which are aligned to form a wall on the lanes. You can pass those obstacles if your character matches the shape or color.
The obstacles are all unique ( no one shares the color nor shape).

My question: Is there a chance to not pass through the barrier of obstacles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really get the question. However If you have one of 4 colors. Moreover you have one of 4 shapes so there are 16 combiations of your character.
To pass obstacle you have to be matched to its color or shape, so **with 10 different obstacles there is 100% chance to pass** . You are able to create 9 different obstacles character will not pass.
Lets say we use two groups of variables {1,2,3,4} and {a,b,c,d}. Character is 2c, so all the obstacles impassible to be passed are:
1a, 1b, 1d
3a, 3b, 3d
4a, 4b, 4d 
10th combination will always match.
Mathematically if you have two groups of x and y elements there is no more than (x-1)(y-1) possibilities of "not passing", and in group of (x-1)(y-1)+1 unique "obstancles" you will always pass at least once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer that actually helped me!

Comment: it is always nice when your answer is marked as answered (star below up and downvotes)